# Are chrome apps 'hybrid apps'?

Tags: google-chrome-app

This is my first time seeing the term 'hybrid app'.  [This](https://developers.google.com/accounts/cookbook/platforms/Hybrid) is all I could find on the topic.  I'm trying to understand if that is just a marketing term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group the app types into 3 categories: Native, Hybrid and Web.

Hybrid apps is a term used for smartphone apps that are not written in the native language of the phone. Another example is PhoneGap, where you write the entire application as a web application (Using html, javascript, css, etc.) which is then wrapped as an app.

Hybrid apps generally have the advantage that they are cheaper and easier to produce, and is easily ported across operating systems, but lacks performance, and some functionality, due to the overhead, and not being run "directly" on the device.

Native apps are applications written using the native code of the device, and web apps are really just phone friendly websites that are opened through a browser.

Long story, short, no it's not just a marketing term, and to answer the title of your question, yes I would say chrome-app qualifies as a Hybrid app

Comment: @tarabyte The context is a bit different on desktop applications. The need for wrapping a web application into a Hybrid app is mostly done for either marketing purposes (people like the feeling of an app, having an icon, splash screen etc.) or for accessing functionality on the device (gps, camera, etc.) more easily. I don't see much use for the term "hybrid applications" on a PC edit: Oh, you removed your comment. Oh well :D

Comment: A Chrome App may be a hybrid app with respect to the underlying OS, but it is a native app on its platform, which is Chrome.